# URL with Port does not work from the internal network

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

We have network with a split domain:

AD Domain: company.com
external Website: company.com

That the website is available in the domain without the need to type www we installed IIS on the DC with a redirect. That works so far.
Now we have a jira installation on our webserver under the URL:

http://jira.company.com:8089

So I created a new DNS entry to jira.company.com on the respective IP Address. No the issue is, that internal it can resolve http://jira.company.com but not http://jira.company.com:8089. From an external computer, it works with

I thought, maybe I have a wrong IP address, but when I replace I can access everything just fine with over this url:

http://[IP]:8089

nslookup to jira.company.com gives me the following result:

```
Server: unknown
Address: [IP DC]

Name: jira.company.com
Address: [ip external]
```

What is the reason for this? And can I fix it somehow on my network?

Comment: *"can resolve http://jira.company.com but not http://jira.company.com:8089"* - DNS is only relevant for the hostname part of the URL and regardless of the port number. Are you certain that internally `nslookup jira.example.com` resolves to the correct IP?

Comment: I added the nslookup result. the name and address to it is correct.

Comment: Since it works without the port and from external,  my thought was if there is something resolved differently when a port is added to the url, so that it won't leave the internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue. There where an old DNS entry for the URL. nslookup resolved the correclty, but somehow my browsers seemed to have chached it (http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).
When I switched to the private mode it worked.